# reading an image file and convert into a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I take an image file and then convert it into a vector to apply the k means function. I want to cluster the images in two types. So it is required to store an image in vector then k means algorithm can be applied. So anyone can help that how can I achieve this?

```
>> mkdir('D:\Matlab\appdata\Data','Ads');
Warning: Directory already exists. 
>> Dir='D:\Matlab\appdata\Data\Ads\*.jpg';  
>>  Imgs=dir(Dir);
>>  for j=1:length(Imgs)
l1=imread(Imgs(j).name);
data=imresize(l1,[500 600]);
mg=rgb2gray(data);
imwrite(mg,['D:\Matlab\appdata\Data\Images\img',num2str(0),'.jpg']);
end
>>  for j=1:length(Imgs)
l1=imread(Imgs(j).name);
data=imresize(l1,[500 600]);
mg=rgb2gray(data);
imwrite(mg,['D:\Matlab\appdata\Data\Images\img',num2str(j),'.jpg']);
end
>> direc=='D:\Matlab\appdata\Data\Images\*.jpg';
>> vector=reshape(imgg(1)',1,[]);
>> imgV=reshape(imgg(1)',[],1);
>>  plotv(imgV,'-');
??? Error using ==> plotv at 22
Matrix must have at least 2 rows.

>> v=reshape(imgg(1)',2,50); 
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

>> imgV

imgV = 

   name: 'img0.jpg'
   date: '31-May-2016 14:37:48'
  bytes: 53732
  isdir: 0
datenum: 7.3648e+005

>> plotv(imgV,'-')
??? Error using ==> plotv at 22
Matrix must have at least 2 rows.
```

In this code the imgV is a struct I want to store it a vector to pass it into K means.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read the image in, then reshape it to be a column vector. If it is an RGB image, you'll want it to be `[M*N x 3]` and if it's grayscale you'll want it to be `[M*N x 1]`. `kmeans` will treat each row of the input as a separate data point.

A general way to do this is:

```
nGroups = 2;
reshaped = reshape(img, [], size(img, 3));
groups = kmeans(reshaped, nGroups);
```

Comment: What is 3 in size(img,3) ?

Comment: @Nabeel_Afzal it is the dimension parameter. It returns the size along the third dimension. For RGB images this will be 3 and four grayscale images this will be 1. I used it here to make this solution work for any type of image.

Comment: '>> groups = kmeans(reshaped,nGroups)

while running this line i am facing this problem 
??? Undefined function or method 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'struct'. 
How to resolve this now?

Comment: @Nabeel_Afzal Why is your `img` variable a `struct`? It should be a 3D array of numbers...

Comment: I want to store the image in vector because i want it to pass it to kmeans. I am new to matlab so i don't know that how can i convert the image into 3D array or vector. Can you help in this regards?

Comment: @Nabeel_Afzal Can you post your code (into your original question) showing how you create the image?